# Optimizing $L_1$ distance with positivity constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Assume $B_\text{old}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$, $p_\text{old}\in\mathbb{R}_+^k$, $w_\text{old}\in\mathbb{\Delta_k}$, and define $b_\text{old}\in\mathbb{R}^m\triangleq B_\text{old}\cdot w_\text{old}$.
$\Delta_{k}=\left\{\mathbf{w}:\mathbf{w}\succeq 0, \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{1}=1\right\}$.

To give some context, $b_\text{old}$ is a weighted average of $m$ features from $k$ observations, and $p_\text{old}$ is a "potential" metric.

Now assume we are given new observations $B_\text{new}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$, and new potential $p_\text{new}\in\mathbb{R}_+^k$.

I'm struggling with solving the following minimization problem:
$$w_\text{new}=\text{argmin}_{w\in\Delta_k} \{\|B_\text{new}\cdot w-b_\text{old}\|_1\},\quad \text{s.t.} \quad (\langle p_\text{new}, w\rangle - \langle p_\text{old}, w_\text{old}\rangle) > \varepsilon,$$
where $\varepsilon > 0$.

Put into words: find new weights such that we suffer the minimal loss, **and** the weighted potential is increased in at least $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Assuming $w$ is your optimization variable, and the others are fixed, then your problem can be reformulated as an LP.